# Sending Simple Automated email using Data Extension instead of list

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to set up a simple automated email using a Data Extension rather than a list?

Answer (score 1):

Some general info regarding sending to data extensions.

> To send a message to a data extension, select the data extension as
>   the list to receive the message. Before you perform this procedure,
>   you must create the data extensions, create the data relationships,
>   and populate the data extension. You can choose to schedule this
>   message or include this message in a program.

[Here is a snippet of code from the docs in C# showing how this is done.](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_email_send_definition/)

```
    //DataExtention to Send to
    DataExtension de = new DataExtension();
    de.ObjectID = "729860f8-7d66-de11-bf42-001e0bbb7678";//This can be obtained via a Retrieve (Named Send_DE)

    //Set Send Definition List for the Email Send Definition
    esd.SendDefinitionList = new SendDefinitionList[1];
    esd.SendDefinitionList[0] = new SendDefinitionList();
    esd.SendDefinitionList[0].Name = "SDL Name";
    esd.SendDefinitionList[0].CustomerKey = "SDL CustomerKey";

    esd.SendDefinitionList[0].SendDefinitionListType = SendDefinitionListTypeEnum.SourceList;
    esd.SendDefinitionList[0].SendDefinitionListTypeSpecified = true;
    esd.SendDefinitionList[0].CustomObjectID = de.ObjectID;
    esd.SendDefinitionList[0].DataSourceTypeID = DataSourceTypeEnum.CustomObject;//This specifies a Data Extention
    esd.SendDefinitionList[0].DataSourceTypeIDSpecified = true;
```

Hope this helps!